# What java List is suitable for thread safe on addAll and clear

Tags: java, collections, thread-safety

I only call addAll and clear of the List, but need it to thread-safe, is there any existing List for this ? Thanks

Comment: "thread-safe" is a big term. If two threads call addAll simultaneously, is it enough to not get a `ConcurrentModificationException`, or do you need all elements from the 1st thread added before the elements from the 2nd?

Comment: You really need to add more detail about the scenario, if you want a high-quality, specific answer.

Answer (score 2):

List is not-synchronized.
So it is not thread-safe.
If you want it as thread-safe means it is possible to make the list as thread-safe, you can use the

[Collections.synchronizedList(List list)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29)

Answer (score 2):

A list created using `Collections.synchronizedList(List list)` will satisfy those requirements, *provided* that the synchronized list is the target object in the `addAll(...)` call, and never the parameter.

If the synchronized list (created as above) is the argument, then the problem is that `addAll(list)` iterates the argument `list`, and iterating a synchronized list is not atomic.  If another thread updates `list` while it is being added, the you are liable to get a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

If you need to do the `addAll(list)` in a thread-safe fashion in the face of concurrent updates to `list`, then you need to make `list` a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a concurrent list implementation in java.util.concurrent. [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) in particular.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use exsting list as Synchronised one, go for `Collections.synchronizedList(list)` or you are creating targeted list, then you can go for `CopyOnWriteArrayList`

Answer (score -1):

CopyOnWriteArrayList is a concurrent replacement for synchronizedList that offers better concurrency in some common situations & eliminates the need to lock or copy the collection during iteration.

The copy on write collections derive their thread safety from the fact that as an effectively immutable object is properly published, no further synchronization is required when accessing it. They implement mutability by creating & republishing a new copy of the collection everytime it is modified. The collection does not throw ConcurrentModificationException regardless of subsequent modifications.